# Java Modal dialog freezes whole application when using jdk 8

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog, freeze

Very rarely, when showing a modal dialog in a Java Swing application using `JDK1.8.0_144`, the whole application gets frozen.

I couldn't find a relevant bug in the JDK bug database. The only one that would seem remotely related is [this one](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8151170) but our application was never minimized whenever it got frozen.

I caught it once in debug and it seems that events are still being processed by the secondary loop (focus events, mouse movement events) but the modal dialog cannot be closed and the user cannot interact with the application.

Obviously my first thought was to update the JDK version but since I could only rarely reproduce the issue I won't be sure if it fixes the issue or not.

Anyone had this happen to them or do you have any suggestion on how to debug or fix?

```
 WARN[09:41:41,482] - SwingCheckerTimer - stacktrace - AWT-EventQueue-0, Id = 22, Priority = 6: WAITING
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
java.awt.EventQueue.getNextEvent(EventQueue.java:608)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:170)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
java.awt.SequencedEvent.dispatch(SequencedEvent.java:107)
java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1671)
java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1623)
java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
```

Comment: do you use multiple windows? I know this can happen if two modal dialoges are active at the same time (I guess because both of them want to keep the focus)

Comment: Yes, most probably multiple modal dialogs were showing up at the same time but all of them from the AWT-Event-Queue. Do you have any reference or link to this sort of issue happening?

Comment: I can't find any source matching this problem. But I had this problem myself when a modal error dialogue froze my application... every single time it poped up (using jdk 8, win7)

Comment: Did you by any chance manage to isolate the issue in a smaller Swing application? Or did you only reproduce it within your application?

Comment: Unfortunately its a long time ago, so I don't have access to the code that 
 caused the bug anymore